# Placing text to the right of multiline equation

Tags: vertical-alignment, text, empheq

I have a piecewise equation, with a curly brace on the right hand side which spans both parts. I wish to place text at the centre of this brace (and hence not really on on the two lines used for the equations) and I am having problems with this.

I am using the empheq package to brace the two lines as I needed to label each equation separately to be able to later reference them. Is there a way to place text to the right of the brace, in the centre, such that it can be seen to apply to both lines (i.e. the domain)? The snippet I am using is below.

```
\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace}]{align}
    \label{eq:NonlinPDEfluid}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (w P) &= \nu \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(w^3 P \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\right) \\            
    \label{eq:NonlinPDEmmtm}
        \delta^2 \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} &= \mu \nu \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} + P -1
\end{empheq}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) always post full minimal examples instead of just sniplets, not everyone might be familiar with `empheq` (this also makes it easier for others to help. (3) `right={\empheqrbrace\quad\text{text}`, is this what you want?

Comment: daleif - (1) Thank you for the welcome. (2) I thought that I had provided enough of an example, I was under the impression that empheq is just a different math environment, however, for future reference, what more should I have included in the example to make it easier to understand? (3) Yes! That works! I think that was the only place I hadn't tried putting text! Thank you

Comment: @TimSimmons We are most happy with a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and that is ready to copy, paste'n' run. This saves time when testing solutions, and it saves even  more time since it answers many questions that we might have to ask otherwise.

Comment: Ah. I see, I will bear that in mind and do that next time. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proper minimal example. As gernot says, we like to have something complete to test.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace\quad \text{text}}]{align}
    \label{eq:NonlinPDEfluid}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (w P) &= \nu \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(w^3 P \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\right) \\            
    \label{eq:NonlinPDEmmtm}
        \delta^2 \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} &= \mu \nu \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} + P -1
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

There has been many examples where users complained about some problem, posting just a sniplet, we give an answer and it turns out that in their real document they were using some packages that that they didn't mention or a special class that changes things.

As for your question, just add the right text to the `right` key along with the right brace.